# PDO query insert special symbol

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$queryInsertUrl= "INSERT INTO oc_url_alias SET query = :pid, keyword = :keyw";
$pid = 'product_id=100002';
$stmtInsertUrl->bindParam(':pid',$pid);
$stmtInsertUrl->bindParam(':keyw',$producturl['keyword']);
$stmtInsertUrl  = $connin->prepare($queryInsertUrl);
$stmtInsertUrl->execute();  
echo $queryInsertUrl;
```

**Result:**

```
INSERT INTO oc_url_alias SET query = 'product_id=100002', keyword = 'yesssss'
```

Above query I tried to insert using PDO, but when I run the code it will return error. Because of **'product_id=100002'**. Everyone know how to fix that? If I delete the = in **product_id=100002** it will return success

Comment: Either [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) directly, don't mix - the former is the better option.

Comment: *Because of 'product_id=100002'.* - I doubt it is because of that, learn about prepared statements. You syntax for your SQL query is incorrect. Overall, your code has many issues and none of them are because of a special symbol.

Comment: learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection. What you are duing has nothing to do with prepared statements

Comment: Also `insert into ... set` is no valid SQL Syntax what you want to do is `update ... set .... `

Comment: The word `QUERY` is a reserved word in MySQL, you cannot use it as a column name, unless you backtick it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware AKAIK, it is a keyword, not a reserved word. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Script47: Indeed, there's no `(R)` behind it in [the list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), anyway the effect is the same.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware anyhow, OP has too many issues and clearly is not interested enough to stick around. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: any example for this query?

Comment: I tired to use bind statements, fail

Comment: Binding is not part of your question, so you won't get an answer to that, please ask a new question. Oh, you completely changed the question, right...

Comment: You prepare then bind you don't bind then prepare

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks around names, so you don't end up using [keywords and reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Your query should then look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `oc_url_alias` SET `query` = 'product_id=100002', `keyword` = 'yesssss'
```

In your changed question you should use this:

```
$queryInsertUrl= "INSERT INTO `oc_url_alias` SET `query` = :pid, `keyword` = :keyw";
```

Comment: cannot to processed. If i try to remove = at **'product_id=100002'**, it can be success to processed